# robots.txt not showing via node.js routes send plain text

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, router, robots.txt

This is driving me nuts... I added a route in my router definition to serve up a plain text robots.txt file. I don't think I have a catchall before the /robots.txt route as the other routes to /mobile and /map work as expected. On my local machine the /robots.txt works fine. Only when deployed to the server does this route not work.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

router.get('/mobile', function (req, res) {
    res.render('mobile');
});

router.get('/map', function (req, res) {
    res.render('map');
});

router.get('/robots.txt', function (req, res) {
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.send('User-agent: *');
});
```

This works well on my local machine but not when deployed to http://geolytix.co.uk/robots.txt

```
Error: Not Found
   at /usr/share/geolytix/app.js:28:13
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/share/geolytix/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   at trim_prefix (/usr/share/geolytix/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
   at /usr/share/geolytix/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
   at Function.process_params (/usr/share/geolytix/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (/usr/share/geolytix/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at /usr/share/geolytix/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
   at next (/usr/share/geolytix/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:256:14)
   at Function.handle (/usr/share/geolytix/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
   at router (/usr/share/geolytix/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
```

My initial guess was that this has something to do with the proxy from nginx to my node server but I can access the site by going to the IP address direct. Yet the robots.txt route fails.

http://139.59.161.58:3000/robots.txt

Edit:

This is line 28 of my app.js
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you restarted your Node server after adding that route? Try requesting `/robots.txt` from Express directly (on your server) instead of going through nginx.

Comment: I suppose it's static file intercept issue. Can you show nginx config, specifically  `location` part in `server`?

Comment: It's not the nginx setting. I can open the site from the IP address but the robots.txt isn't opening. http://139.59.161.58:3000/robots.txt

Comment: i use PM2 to run the node application and use the reload method of PM2 to reload after git updates. This worked for all other updates apart from the robots.txt request.

Comment: The error message you're showing isn't Express's default (in fact, it doesn't throw errors at all when it can't find a particular URI, it'll just return a 404 response), so that error is being generated somewhere in your code (and handled by what I assume is an error handler on line 28 of `app.js`). Do you have a route that looks like `/:param`?

Comment: Line 28 is the line after I define to use the routes. It's followed by an error handler. I commented the error handler and reloaded the app through PM2. No change though.

Comment: My last suggestion: enable debugging by setting the `DEBUG` environment variable to `*`, and see what is getting logged for requests to `/robots.txt`. Not sure how to set environment variables for PM2, but you can also set it at the top of `app.js` (before any `require`'s): `process.env.DEBUG = '*'`

Comment: It's a problem with PM2. I haven't fixed this yet but I should be able to.

Comment: Adding the debug to app.js made me realize that the hosted app was cached and the actual app had crashed days ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application had crashed after 15 failed restarts in PM2 with a cached version still being served. The robots.txt route was not in the cache. I am sorry for having wasted your time. At least I have now a better understanding how to use PM2.

D

Answer (score 0):

This is because nginx configuration is set to *intercept static files requests*.

Some part like this:

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...
        location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
            root /usr/local/.../public;
            access_log off;
            expires max;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Is taking care of handling `robots.txt` even before it gets to Express.js routing middleware.

You should exclude file from nginx configuration to allow routing handle it.

Comment: It's not the nginx config I am afraid. If I go to the IP address directly I am still unable to get the robots.txt.

Comment: Also doesn't make sense, because the error message is Express's, so the requests _are_ being proxied.

Comment: I feel it's the only thing that could cause this issue - how this path is handled by server. Code is perfectly fine (and it works on localhost). Anyway, you trying to say that if you access site by IP, nginx is not handling request anymore? It depends on how you configured it.